# Regulator to feed Arduino VIN with 12V?

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, 12v

I am quite new to electronic and I'd like to build a setup plugged with a 12V PS (because there is a water pump in my setup).

But at the same time, I'd like to feed the Arduino VIN with the same power supply. Is it a good practice to use a regulator to go from 12V to 5V for a H24 setup? I mean, will it burn because of too much power dissipation?

If no, how can I supply the Arduino VIN in a more elegant way?

Comment: I suggest using a step-down buck converter, to convert your 12V to 5V. This way you do not have to worry about too much power dissipation.

Comment: A buck converter is probably unecessary for the small load of an Arduino unless your ultimate source is a battery.  If the onboard regulator is getting hot you can split the heat load with an external 8 or 9v regulator.  The Arduino Vin requures around 7 volts minimum to operate properly, if you have only 5v you would need to route it through the USB input.

Comment: Arduino cannot be powered by 5V through the plug, the input voltage should be between 6 and 20V.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino MEGA, Due, Pro, Pro Mini and UNO are all capable of handling an input voltage of 12V. The limits are even higher. If you're using a different one, check the [product specification](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products)

Cheers.